# Remove new line characters from data recieved from node event process.stdin.on("data")

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I've been looking for an answer to this, but whatever method I use it just doesn't seem to cut off the new line character at the end of my string.

Here is my code, I've attempted to use `str.replace()` to get rid of the new line characters as it seems to be the standard answer for this problem:

```
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
    var str;
    str = data.toString();
    str.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
    return console.log("user typed: " + str + str + str);
});
```

I've repeated the `str` object three times in console output to test it. Here is my result:

```
hi
user typed: hi
hi
hi
```

As you can see, there are still new line characters being read between each `str`. I've tried a few other parameters in `str.replace()` but nothing seems to work in getting rid of the new line characters.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are calling `string.replace` without assigning the output anywhere.  The function does not modify the original string - it creates a new one - but you are not storing the returned value.

Try this:

```
...
str = str.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
...
```

---

However, if you actually want to remove *all* whitespace from around the input (not just newline characters at the end), you should use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
...
str = str.trim();
...
```

It will likely be more efficient since it is already implemented in the Node.js binary.

Comment: Wow... such a simple thing to overlook, but caused me so much hassle. Thanks! I'll mark this one correct when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to console output the value of `str` without updating it.
You should have done this

```
str = str.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
```

before console output.

Answer (score -10):

you need to convert the data into **JSON** format.
**JSON.parse(data)** you will remove all new line character and leave the data in **JSON** format.