# Take input in javascript from console and store in array without new line \n

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Var stdin = process.openStdin();
stdin.addListener("data",function(d){});
```

How can I fetch input from this? I've tried `d.toString.trim();`
But later when I push in the array it is also pushing `\n` in the array.

Comment: is it a node.js application? Because of process.

Comment: `Var` -> `var`, but probably should be `let`. That should also be `d.toString().trim()` as the function call brackets are absolutely necessary in JavaScript.

Comment: Why do you need `openStdin()`? It's already there as [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) and you can immediately read from it. Remember you can `pipe()` it to things using streams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all text from stdin to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441025/read-all-text-from-stdin-to-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();
let arr=[];
stdin.addListener("data",function(d){

arr.push(d.toString().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " "));
console.log(arr);

});
```

See [repl](https://repl.it/join/zhbkmxxj-shubhamdixit863)

Reference [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794241/remove-new-line-characters-from-data-recieved-from-node-event-process-stdin-on/20794254)-for `string replace`

Comment: Or `replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')` to just get rid of the newlines.

Comment: I'm new to this. this is currently storing as single element as in array at position 0. How can I split them into different elements.